# How to calculate object size from a heap dump?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I have an object heap dump taken through Jmap. I have also seen the dump through Jhat. I need to calculate the size of the object. How do I do it?

In dump I can see for example:

```
Class Name,                    total objects,          total size
com.test.app.CallRecord ,             2194       ,            446324
```

So if I calculate 446324/2194 = 203. So 203 bytes is the size of 1 CallRecord object. Is it so? I have a confusion over here. What is this size? Does it include the size of references as well?

I'm confused. Someone has asked me to let them know the size of the CallRecord Object. Should I tell them 203 bytes? I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Does 203 bytes includes the size of reference comes under CallRecord object as well?

How to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if the total size is the **shalow** size or the **retained** size.

1. **Shallow size**

   The shallow size of an object is amount of memory used to store the object itself. The referenced objects are not taken into account.
2. **Retained size**

   The retained size of an object is the amount of memory that can be freed when the object is collected by the garbage collector.

Comment: OK Thanks.Could you please let me know how to get both the sizes.I have searched on net and found OQL(object query language). I have tried it but couldn't successed.Can you help me.

Comment: @VJS you can get these sizes with tools like Eclipse MAT

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use some kind of memory analyzing tool (profiler). YourKit is great for this, but quite costly, Eclipse MAT is also good, and it's free. VisualVM is quite simple, but it's good enough and free as well.. (I've quite often ended up using all of them, since they all have some things that the other lack..)